# Google Sheets: Create 1D array of a combination of values repeated a different amount of times

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create an array in google sheets based on a combination of two text values. Or perhaps a better explanation is I need to provide a position X for value B in a 5 cell array of values A and output the resultant combination of 5 cells based on the position chosen. See example below:

| Value 1 | Value 2 | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | X |

Different Combinations:

| Pos0 | Pos1 | Pos2 | Pos3 | Pos4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | A | A | A |
| A | B | A | A | A |
| A | A | B | A | A |
| A | A | A | B | A |
| A | A | A | A | B |

This formula will ultimately be nested inside an if statement...Please help!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: If you wanted the whole array, it would be =ArrayFormula(if(munit(5),B2,A2)) but I think you mean it to be like @doubleunary's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that value 1 is in cell `A2`, value 2 in `B2` and the zero-indexed position in `C2`, use this formula in a free row:

`=arrayformula( if( sequence(1, 5, 0) = C2, B2, A2 ) )`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you kindly! Can you explain how the different cell values modify the sequence if statement?

Also how would I go about front loading the array with 0-2 blank cells depending on a new input variable?

Comment: See [sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Just in case, also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)